# Data validation error in Django Serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to add multiple ManytoMany relationship in a model but when I am trying to add the data it shows `OrderedDict()` in the validated data in serializer

Models.py

```
class Client(models.Model):
    
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    client_name = models.CharField(max_length=500, default=0)
    client_shipping_address = models.CharField(max_length=500, default=0,blank=True, null=True)


class Group(models.Model):

    emp = models.ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete=models.CASCADE)  #try user
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500, default=0)
    groupmodels = models.ManyToManyField(GroupModels)
    sender_clients = models.ManyToManyField(Client)
    receiver_clients = models.ManyToManyField(ReceiverClient)
    warehouses = models.ManyToManyField(Warehouse)
```

Views.py

```
class GroupsCreateAPIView(CreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        d = request.data.copy()
        print(d)
        serializer = GroupsSerializer(data=d)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            print("Serializer data", serializer.data)
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            print('error')
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Serilalizer.py

```
class GroupSenderClientSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Client
        fields = "__all__"
        read_only_fields = ('user',)


class GroupsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    groupmodels = GroupModelsSerializer(many=True)
    sender_clients = GroupSenderClientSerializer(many=True)
    receiver_clients = ReceiverClientSerializer(many=True)
    warehouses = WarehouseSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Group
        fields = "__all__"


    def create(self, validated_data):
        print("v data", validated_data)
        items_objects = validated_data.pop('groupmodels', None)
        sc_objects = validated_data.pop('sender_clients', None)
        rc_objects = validated_data.pop('receiver_clients', None)
        ware_objects = validated_data.pop('warehouses', None)
        prdcts = []
        sc = []
        rc = []
        ware = []
        for item in items_objects:
            i = GroupModels.objects.create(**item)
            prdcts.append(i)
        instance = Group.objects.create(**validated_data)
        print("sc objects", sc_objects)

        if len(sc_objects)>0:
            for i in sc_objects:
                print("id", i['id'])
                inst = Client.objects.get(pk=i['id'])
                sc.append(inst)

        if len(rc_objects)>0:
            for i in rc_objects:
                inst = ReceiverClient.objects.get(pk=i['id'])
                rc.append(inst)

        if len(ware_objects)>0:
            for i in ware_objects:
                inst = Warehouse.objects.get(pk=i['id'])
                ware.append(inst)

        instance.groupmodels.set(prdcts)
        instance.sender_clients.set(sc)
        instance.receiver_clients.set(rc)
        instance.warehouses.set(ware)
        return instance
```

The initial data in the serializer is like the following

```
initial_data = {'name': '546', 'emp': 14, 'sender_clients': [{'id': 3}, {'id': 4}], 'receiver_clients': [], 'warehouses': [], 'groupmodels': []}


validated_data = {'groupmodels': [], 'sender_clients': [OrderedDict(), OrderedDict()], 'receiver_clients': [], 'warehouses': [], 'name': '546', 'emp': <Employee: Employee object (14)>}
```

Please help me figure out why the `sender_clients` is converted to blank `dicts` and how do I change it?

Comment: Can you add your view's code? Serializer's create method is not called. There must be something wrong in your view. I guess serializer.is_valid() and serializer.save() commands are missing.

Comment: @ÇağatayBarın I have both of them in the views

Comment: Yet you still keep that to yourself only :)

Comment: @ÇağatayBarın I have updated the question

Comment: Your serializer can't validate your sender_clients data. It has only id but ClientSerializer expects user field. Make the user field on ClientSerializer read only by adding this line below your fields line in ClientSerializer.
`read_only_fields = ('user', )`
Can you do this and try again?

Comment: @ÇağatayBarın I tried that and it works but i got an empty orderedDict in the validated data  `'sender_clients': [OrderedDict()],`

Answer (score 1):

when you used `ManyToManyField` in your Django model I think you don't need to implement any nested serializer class or overwriting action at the create. If you change your serializer to this:

```
class GroupsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Group
        fields = "__all__"
```

Django-Rest-Framework add some `PrimaryKeyRelatedField` fields for each many-many-field in your model to this serializer therefore you `repr()` object of this serializer at the console probably sew like this:

```
class GroupsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    .....
    groupmodels = PrimaryKeyRelatedField(allow_empty=False, many=True, queryset=GroupModels.objects.all())
    sender_clients = PrimaryKeyRelatedField(allow_empty=False, many=True, queryset=Client.objects.all())
    receiver_clients = PrimaryKeyRelatedField(allow_empty=False, many=True, queryset=ReceiverClient.objects.all())
    warehouses = PrimaryKeyRelatedField(allow_empty=False, many=True, queryset=Warehouse.objects.all())
    .....
```

therefore you request body for those fields change to this:

```
{
    .....
    groupmodels: [1,2,3,...],
    sender_clients: [1,2,3,...],
    receiver_clients: [1,2,3,...],
    warehouses: [1,2,3,...],
    .....
}
```

those ids must be created before, If you want to create at the same time when you was created `Group` with the duplicated rows at the destination models, should be overwrite with some change in the serializer. But for avoiding to problem and **best practice** better to implement create action for destination models at the other place like your views or other API for create them. Better to avoiding to implement logic at the serializer. At the future you can control on access on create API for each user role or responsive implementation for each of them.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the order dict to dict like this:

```
 data = validated_data.dict()
```

in your case for list of sc_objects:

```
objs = [obj.dict() for obj in sc_objects]
```